# How do I keep my fish from dying?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Commander Shepard is a busy spectre. Running around the galaxy, shooting reaper scum, and trying to save the day. So I don't begrudge her buying some fish to at least make her quarters look a little nicer.

But at the same time, Shepard spends so much time flitting about, that... well, let's just say that Earth isn't the only place where Organic Life is dying out.

In Mass Effect 2, Shepard could eventually enlist Kelly Chambers to feed Shep's fish (she even returns them when you run into her on the Citadel!), but Kelly's no longer part of the Normandy's crew, and so Shepard's aquarium lies fallow.

Is there some way to automatically feed the fish? Is there no hope for these piscine soldiers? Is there no way to prevent them from dying every time Shep goes on a mission without feeding them? Forget Palavan or Earth, think of the Fish!

Comment: Isn't Shepard a guy? "So I don't begrudge her buying some fish to at least make her quarters look a little nicer."

Comment: @Emerica Shepard can be either male or female, it is up to the player.

Comment: @bwarner Mother of god. ME was a game I just totally skipped in the gaming world haha.

Comment: I get to have FISH? I need to play this game more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a whopping 25,000 credits, the Aquarium VI is available for sale on the Citadel, at the Elkoss Combine Arsenal Supplies terminal (where you first find Barla Von) in the Presdium Commons.

In addition to breaking your piggy bank, this pricey item's description also indicates that it will automatically feed your fish:

> With so many exotic speices of fish available in today's galactic market, it takes an expert to maintain an ideal aquarium. This VI automatically dispenses food, adjusts the temperature, pH, and algae content of the water, and even talks to the fish when you're not around, leaving you free to enjoy your aquatic friends without fear of killing them.

If 25,000 credits isn't expensive enough for your tastes, you can also head on down to the Alliance Requisitions terminal in the Normandy's cargo bay, where you can buy the same Elkoss Combine Aquarium VI for base price + a 2,500 credit markup.

Comment: Hm. Guns or Fish...

Comment: You mean you can't come on to Kelly's replacement and have her do it?  What a rip-off.

Comment: @RavenDreamer guns or butter?

Comment: Man ... I knew fish were expensive to keep, but this is just silly... you're off saving the universe and you can't get some non-com to feed your fish for you??? :-)

Comment: @MBraedley Possibly, but Kelly's replacement doesn't swing that way with male Shepard.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Interesting.  Maybe I won't be playing my loyal male Shep first...

Comment: @TimStone Could you add something about how often you need to manually feed the fish if you don't want to drop 25k on the aquarium?

Comment: @Sterno Sure thing, I'll see what I can come up with

Answer (score 1):

As I recall from ME2, if you didn't go and feed your fish after every mission (though some have said they've done up to three missions before expiration) they'd die. I would imagine it is the same for ME3. I ponied up the cash for the VI because by golly I hate seeing dead fish and feeling like a total failure as a human being as a result.