# Who are the numerous that died?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When I started a new ME3 game, it asked me to choose if Ashley, Kaiden, or Numerous died. Who are the numerous? I chose *numerous* because I hoped that meant some no-names, but if *numerous* is the entire ME2 cast that would be quite fail.

Who are numerous?

**In order to clear up some confusion, when you start a new game, the following individuals are dead, *regardless* of your selection at this point in creation:**

- Jack
- Thane
- Wrex
- Samara (Not listed on the wall because it's assumed she was never recruited, but died at Morinth's hands)
- All *Mass Effect 2* Normandy Crew Members *except* for Doctor Chakwas (this means Ken, Gabby, Chambers)
- One of Ashley or Kaiden. If you select 'Numerous', this will automatically be whichever one of the two is the same sex as Shepard. Otherwise, you will have chosen this.
- The original Council

**All answers should provide concrete evidence of any claims made. Please do not speculate. Please keep in mind that the *default profile* includes several notable casualties. This question is about which casualties make the 'Numerous' selection *distinct*.**

Comment: I'm not sure who exactly it is, but I think it means either Ashley or Kaiden PLUS others.  There is no way to have both Ashley and Kaiden alive.

Comment: @bwarner thanks, I don't really like Ashley or Kaiden, I like ME2's cast much more, I'd trade both of them for ME2 dudes in a heartbeat. I mostly want to know if I made the wrong choice and needs to restart.

Comment: I do believe numerous includes some ME2 characters. How far along into the game are you?

Comment: @kotekzot Just got onto Citadel for the first time after clearing Mars.

Comment: If you made the "Numerous" choice and play long enough to get aboard the Normandy, there's a memorial wall in the ship. I believe this wall lists the names of all Normandy crew members that have died in the line of duty. IIRC, it's across from the elevator on either the crew deck or the engineering deck.

Comment: That's not far at all, you should have no problem replaying if you choose to.

Comment: @kotekzot yes I have no problem restarting. Just want to know who died. If somebody could answer that that would be fantastic.

Comment: Well, if you're on the Citadel you should be able to follow @JonQuarfoth's lead with the memorial wall.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Samara didn't die with the default settings (her name would have been on the memorial wall). Rather, she was never recruited in the first place, which has more or less the same net effect.

Comment: She's dead. She just didn't die aboard the Normandy. She's assumed to have been killed by Morinth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is the memorial plaque wall when you start with a new character and select the "numerous" option. As you'll note, most of the squad members from Mass Effect 2 are still alive:

[image: the numerous that died]

Those names underlined in blue are the original crew members of the Normandy SR-1 who died in the beginning of Mass Effect 2, along with the two squad members Ashley Williams and Urdnot Wrex (marked by blue squares). Kaidan was chosen to be alive because I was playing a female Shepard; when playing a male Shepard, Ashley will be the Vermire survivour.

Those names underlined in orange are all crew and squad members from the Normandy SR-2. Those marked with an orange circle, Gabriella Daniels, Kenneth Donnelly, and Kelly Chambers, would have all made notable appearances in Mass Effect 3 had they not died. More specifically, the former two can be brought back aboard the Normandy in their usual positions as engineers, and Kelly Chambers is a potential romance/fish keeper* depending on your interactions with her in the previous game.

Thane Krios and Jacqueline Nought (Jack) appear to be the only squad member from Mass Effect 2 that's listed as having died, and are highlighted on the wall by the orange square.

Everyone else not on this list is presumed to be alive, and not one of the "numerous who died." In particular, Garrus, Tali, Miranda, and Jacob are all listed as alive. However, the game will act as though you never met Samara/Mordinth, Grunt, Katsumi, and Zaeed, effectively killing them. It will also act as though the original Council died during the attack on the Citadel in Mass Effect 1.

<sup>*that is, she returns your fish from Mass Effect 2 to you; you need the aquarium VI or extreme patience [to keep them alive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53861/how-do-i-keep-my-fish-from-dying)</sup>

The problem of course is that this is the same list of people who would have died if you had simply chosen the Ashley/Kaidan option. In comparing the two save files, one from a "numerous" selection, and one from a "Kaidan" selection (using male Shepard to keep a consistent Vermire casualty), there's actually very few differences between the two scenarios.

The tables below illustrate the difference in game variables before you perform any action:

```
PlotID  | Numerous | Kaidan dies
--------+----------+------------
17807   | true     | false
18005   | false    | true
18122   | false    | true
21569   | false    | true

PlotInt | Numerous | Kaidan dies
--------+----------+------------
10393   | (unset)  | 3
```

At the moment it's unfortunately unclear what these changes represent, because they don't directly map to any of the significant and/or labeled plot events that the game has. Presumably they have some noticeable impact, however, so I'm going to keep digging until I get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Hmmm... The problem of course is that Wrex, Thane, Jack, Gabby, Ken and Kelly are all assumed to have died anyway, regardless of whether you select 'numerous'.

Comment: Jenkins is the very first casualty from ME 1, whom Ashley promptly replaces. Chakwas has some stories about him. The other orange names *are* from the SR2.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Whoops, indeed. Fixed the image, at least.

Answer (score -2):

Per the [Rarity Guide](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/1653/1/Mass-Effect-3-Character-Creation-Guide/Page1.html):

> **Numerous**
>
> The deaths of numerous squadmates and friends have begun to play a significant role in Commander Shepard's psychological profile. The burden of inevitable combat loss after so many high-risk missions weighs heavily on Shepard.
>
> Note: Numerous means that Either Kaidan or Ashely, as well as many other crew members, died. There will be a memorial later in the game aboard the Normandy mentioning those deaths, if you choose this option.

Edit: Removed memorial wall image and name list.

Comment: This doesn't help those of us who don't want to create a new game with "Numerous" deaths, play up to the point where we can get on the Normandy, and then go to the memorial and look at the name list. Can you (or someone else) provide that list? Based on his comments I think Ben is probably interested in which squadmates from the previous two games are assumed to have died. I know I am, anyway!

Comment: Fair enough. Answer updated.

Comment: That screenshot *does not* represent the Numerous that have died if you select it at character creation. The memorial wall is *dynamic*. It updates as you play. There are a number of names on that list that die in the course of ME3. Most notably, a clever viewer will note the presence of **both** Ashley Williams and Kaidan Alenko. While *one* of them will always be included among the numerous, *one* of them will always not be included, but can die further into the campaign.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz it's possible to reach the memorial before you get anyone else killed isn't it? I at least don't know of anyone that dies due to Shep before you can first view the memorial. Wouldn't the difference between numerous and not numerous equal the people that die because of the option?

Comment: @BenBrocka Yep. Take a look at the prior edit to this answer to see what my comment was referring to.