# Does the Aquarium VI serve any purpose?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The store Elkoss Combine Arsenal Supplies sells an Aquarium VI for a rather large fee of 25000 credits.

I'm curious as to whether or not this Aquarium is an upgrade to the one I *already* own, or of it's merely made available to those who were unable to import a *Mass Effect 2* save file in which the original Aquarium *should* be in Shepard's Cabin?

Comment: The answer to this question should fill you in on the details. - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53861/how-do-i-keep-my-fish-from-dying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an add-on to your existing aquarium, not a replacement.  It's sole purpose is to keep your fish fed so that you don't have to do it manually after each mission.  Kelly, once properly motivated, served this purpose in Mass Effect 2.

Comment: Wait, my fish can *die*?! I *knew* I had to buy the koi twice...

Comment: You mean you didn't see them floating upside-down?

Comment: I did not... =( My poor fish...